# Are Gaur/Gaud Brahmins connected to Gaudiya Vaishnavism Sampradaya? Are some Sampradaya named after sects of founding Brahmins?

Tags: tradition, brahmins, gaudiya-vaishnavism, gotra, sampradaya

Any history of Gaur Brahmins and their specific spiritual lineage is appreciated. What sampradaya were followed by Gaur Brahmins? (or are followed by Gaur Brahmins)

Gaur Brahmins have the following 12 gotras:

1. Gautam Brahmins (like me)
2. Srivastava Brahmins
3. Harit Gotra/Kulshresth/Haryanvi Brahmins
4. Vashishta Gotra
5. Sorabh/Saurabh Gotra
6. Valmiki Gaur Gotra
7. Hans gotra
8. Bhatt gotra
9. Dalabhya gotra
10. Suryadhwaja gotra
11. Mathur gotra
12. Mandavya Gotra

Any help is appreciated. If any Gaur Brahmin is reading this, do tell us what Sampradaya you are connected to. (If any)

Comment: Are you possibly talking abt [this ?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaud_Saraswat_Brahmin)